# When are attributive nouns plural?

Tags: grammatical-number, compounds, attributive-nouns, noun-phrases

If I want to say:

> "development of special weapons was
> the first point in Hitler's
> program..."

I will say this (a better form):

> "special weapon development was..."

OK...

is it

> "special weapon development"

or

> "special weapons development" (note
> the plural...)

What's the grammar rule in order to understand how to use this very used form?

Comment: See also: https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/229726

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As a rule, the singular form is used for the first part of a compound noun. So, when in doubt, use the singular. There are three kinds of exceptions:

1. If the singular would be ambiguous, as in "a singles bar": a single bar means just one bar.
2. If the plural used to be a singular possessive, which sounds the same: I think "ladies man" (a man who likes flirting with women etc.) comes from the possessive "lady's man", which is also used. It might also be partly due to category 1, since a "lady man" is now generally an effeminate man.
3. Okay I lied. This is not really a category. There just are exceptions. Often (but not always) the plural is used because a certain word is usually heard in plural in a certain sense, such as "trades union" and "weapons development". I also believe "clothes rack" is fairly acceptable nowadays. It seems the trend is towards using the plural more than in the past, which some traditionalists abhor.

Comment: OK... well, I knew that I had to use singular but I know that some compound used plural too, that's why I asked... well it seems that in most case I must pay attention on how it sounds... ahahah

Comment: I think "ladies man" is more likely to come from a plural possessive than from a singular possessive. There are a number of examples of plural posessives being used as adjectival phrases rather than as determiner phrases, such as "children's clothing," "a women's magazine," "a men's shoe store" or "an old wives' tale."

Comment: @sumelic: It seems *ladies man, ladies' man,* and *lady's man* all exist. I wouldn't know which is "original", if any; but I do suspect there to be a category of words where plural and singular possessive are confused.

Comment: Since *clothes* doesn't have a singular (*a cloth rack* doesn't mean the same thing at all), *clothes rack* is inevitable, like *jeans jacket*. (Of course, there are other pluralia tantum you make singular for compound nouns, like *scissor kick* and *bagpipe music*.)

Comment: @Peter _Clothes_ doesn't have a plural either. And it's not a plural. It's non-count (yes, in plural form and taking plural agreement).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: My clothes are skimpy.

Comment: @Cerberus The test for countness is 'does the usage accept a numeral?' Here, *_My 7 / 12.5 / 1 / dozen clothes are skimpy._ It's a _plural-form plural-agreement-afforded non-count noun._

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Plurality ≠ countability.

Comment: @Cerberus 'A plural noun' is ill-defined. 'Data' is plural in form but almost always used as non-count. Even more so 'news'. _Are these 'plural nouns'_? 'Headquarters' is plural in form, but usually used with a singular verb form and referring to one site (though '2 new headquarters are ...' is fine). _Is it a 'plural noun'_? It only makes sense to categorise usages by (1) form, (2) countness, (3) agreement. One can then look at etic countability ('furniture': (1) singular in form, (2) usually non-count, (3) singular verb form ... (4) count**able** referents).

Comment: Summary: the usual scenario is that the premodifying (attributive) noun is in singular form, but this is not always the case. Travellers checks, systems analysts, women doctors and dogs homes (contrast donkey sanctuaries) are exceptions: one has to check usage.