# Is it correct to say "I write children books" (not possessive case)?

Tags: possessives

Although Children's books is what everybody says, I would like to understand why the genitive case is applied in such case.

If I write books for children, children is an adjective here; not the owners of my book! The word "children" just defines or characterizes the type of books I write. Therefore, it's an adjective.

So, I understand that genitive/possessive case ("I write children's book")  is incorrect grammar.

My question is: is the genitive case here really accepted as right? If I use "I write children books" (following the grammar principle) as as I say "I write pets books" (books about pets, and not possessions of pets) - would I be incorrect? Why?

Comment: General Reference - *children* is never used adjectivally, as could be established by consulting any dictionary.

Comment: @FumbleFingers True, but the example sentence is problematic: *children* is not necessarily an adjective there. It could be hyperbole, and mean "I write children long letters".

Comment: Did you read what [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genitive_case) has to say about the genetive case? It has a nice description of non-possessive uses of the genetive case, demonstrating how the fact that children are not necessarily the _owners_ of these books does not negate the correctness of "Children's books." A quote from there: "It often marks a noun as being the possessor of another noun; however, it can also indicate various other relationships than possession."

Comment: @MετάEd: I can't really see that. OP specifically says *I write books **for** children*, so it would be perverse to place any other interpretation on *children books* here.

Comment: I read multiple dictionary entries for *children* (actually, *child*), and while yes, it's always listed as a noun, in English we regularly use words in grammatical positions they're not nominally suited for. So I think this is a case of: careful, just because it's absolutely obvious to you as a native speaker, that doesn't mean it's totally straightforward, and it definitely doesn't mean it's a dumb question.

Comment: I know regret having voted to close. Apparently not everyone is clear on *why* we don't use *children* adjectivally. I think it's because we don't use *any* plural nouns as adjectives - but we don't always consciously recognise this because most plurals end in "s" (which gets conflated with possessive **'s**). But even if I'm right on that score, I don't see it being spelt out as "the correct answer" (and of course, maybe I'm wrong! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's true that OP provides context which clarifies the meaning, but my point is that the sentence itself, which doesn't provide that context, could be read more than one way.

Comment: @MετάEd: That's why we're always asking for "more context, please". Which in this case was provided. Just about any short utterance can have multiple meanings, particularly if we allow contrived interpretations (not that I can come up with even a contrived interpretation justifying my *know/now* typo two comments above this one! :)

Comment: We use _children's_ as an adjective rather often. At the library: _You can find that in the children's section_. At the family reunion: _Jane, you'll have to sit at the children's table_. On television: _The network plays children's cartoons on Saturday morning._ At the doctor's office: _You'll have to take your daughter to the children's hospital to see a specialist_.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, I agree with that, but the OP is only providing the context in the question, not necessarily in the original text. The only reasonable thing is to point out that the sentence can be read more than one way, and that if you want it to read as intended (which was explained in the question), you'll need the original text to provide additional context.

Comment: @MετάEd: You've lost me there. Surely OP *is* providing "the original text" - at least, for the purposes of the question as asked here. What difference does it make if those words happen to arise in some other context with a different meaning?

Answer (score 14):

There are some interesting points here. One is whether the apostrophe (’) serves any purpose, but we can leave that for another day.

We speak of *children’s books*, not because, in this context, the books **belong to** the children, but because the books are **for** children. *Children’s* acts as a modifier rather than a determiner. As the ‘Longman Grammar of Spoken and Written English’ says,

> [such] genitives have the role of classifying the reference of the
>   head noun: the question answered here is ‘What kind of X? . . . In
>   many cases, a classifying genitive is equivalent to an adjective or a
>   noun modifier . . .

To take up that last point, *children’s books* could, just about, be replaced with *juvenile books* or *junior books*. We can certainly speak of *adult literature* as well as *adults' literature*.

I don’t think *pets books* would normally be found. Instead you might possibly see a section in a bookshop for *pet books*. A better example might be *animal books* (not *animals' books*), which clearly refers to books about animals rather than books for animals.

Comment: I don't think "apostrophise or not?" is the issue here. The question is whether you can use a "bare" plural form "adjectivally". In my opinion, you can't *ever* really do this. We go along with it in things like *Battersea Dogs Home* because we're getting used to discarding "redundant" apostrophes, but where the plural form doesn't end in "s", it simply doesn't work.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. Yes, I'm sure you're right.

Comment: Note that a possessive does not necessarily indicate ownership in the sense of legal property rights. It can mean many sorts of association. Like it's common for people in an office to say, "This is Bob's desk." That doesn't mean that Bob owns the desk and has the right to take it home, sell it, etc., but merely that the company has designated it as being for use by Bob for the time being. Likewise we say things like "the car's steering wheel", even though a car is not a person and can't own anything.

Comment: Hmm, I'm struck by the inconsistency in our language here. We say "children's book" for books aimed at children, but "adult books" for books aimed at adults. Why does the first use the possessive and the second does not? I doubt there's a real reason, it's probably just convention.

Comment: @Jay: Per my earlier comments, "adult" is a *singular* noun, and it's perfectly common for us to use those as adjectives. What we *don't* do is use *plural* nouns as adjectives (it just sometimes *sounds* as if we do, because in the spoken form you can't really distinguish the possessive **'s** from pluralising "s").

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not disagreeing with you. I just noticed that in the specific case of adult vs children, you'd think we'd use symmetrical constructions, i.e. either "child books" and "adult books"; or "children's books" and "adults' books", but we don't.

Comment: @Jay: Well, I'm just saying the "asymmetry" arises from the fact that children is an irregular plural. Language is primarily spoken, not written, so it doesn't make much difference with most nouns whether we think of a final "s" as denoting plural or "possession/association". But I think people do show some consistency. If your 8-year-old points to the "top shelf" in the  rack at the newsagents, you might say *"No, darling! Those are **adult's** comics! These are the **children's** comics down here!"*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hmm, your theory about the irregular plural making the difference is plausible. Well, I don't want to beat the issue to death. It was just an odd comment.

Comment: @Jay: Sure. It's only an off-the-cuff theory anyway, but I do wish I hadn't voted to close. I hope it'll stay open (or get re-opened), and maybe someone more knowledgeable than me will either back it up or shoot it down.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: you're right in general about not using plural nouns as modifiers, but the rule is not absolute. When I worked on a _solid modelling_ software package in the 80's (for modelling solid objects), some of our competitors described their products as _solids modelling_ systems (actually as _solids modeling_, because they were American), presumably to make clear that _solid_ was nominal modifier rather than an adjective.

Comment: @Colin: A Google "site search" confirmed my suspicion that [I'd seen that on ELU before](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/48680/2637) (in one of your answers, unsurprisingly! :)

Comment: @Barrie England:  Barrie, you said the best! Thank you for your polite, clear, sensible answer!  I still don't know why we can use juvenile book, as a book for juveniles; and we can't use child book, as a book for children.  But it's ok.... mysteries of the languages - they all have their peculiarities.

Comment: @Uba: Kind of you to say so.

Answer (score 9):

Grammar is as it is, not as you would like it to be.

*A story book*, *a picture book*, *a fiction book* are all grammatical, but *a children book*  is not, at least in the sense you mean it (It is possibly grammatical in the sense of *a book about children*, but is not in common use even in that sense).

Comment: If we assume that "grammatical" means "acceptable to most competent speakers", I suggest *a children book* isn't grammatical in any context. We simply don't use pluralised nouns in that way, except where the plural form ends in "s" (and can thus get confused with the possessive **'s**). I suppose someone somewhere has said *"It's a **men** thing"*, but even without my bold text, you just *know* it would only be said facetiously, with implied "quotes" around the plural word being used ungrammatically.

Answer (score 8):

The problem here is that basically "children's books" is an idiom. It is not incorrect to put two nouns together, but sometimes it goes against an established convention.

For instance "white and black photograph" is not incorrect, but it is strange because we only ever hear "black and white photograph".

A "driver's license" could be a "driver license" or "driving license". But it isn't, and that's that. It sounds strange because we are accustomed to using "driver's license" as a canned phrase.

"Children's book" has a more specific meaning, that the book belongs to children, and isn't about children.

Compare with "people's republic", which says something different from "people republic".

If we use A B, where A and B are nouns, there is a relationship between A and B in that an A B is a kind of B, which is somehow restricted to a narrower set, as qualified by A.

But A's B is more specific. There is a relationship bewteen A and B such that A's B is a kind of B, which belongs to A.

A "children book" or "child book" could be about children (for example rearing them) rather than for children, the way "car manual" is about a car (whereas the "owner's manual" is clearly not about the owner).

Comment: This answer does not address the question, and most of its paragraphs are irrelevant. And we certainly do say _driving licence_ where I live, though I believe that people in some other country say _driver's license_.

Comment: @Kaz: This answer DOES ADDRESS MY QUESTION! I am the one who asked the question, and this is the best ever answer in here! That's exactly what I was afraid of: a convention. It may look like incorrect grammar,but it has been established as so. By the way, *Colin Fine*, I live in Illinois, USA and people here do say driver's license, and I always thought that it was grammatically incorrect, but hey... it's a convention! And that's how it is, then! THANK YOU so much, Kaz! You made my day!  :)

Answer (score 3):

There is a move away from the use of the apostrophe in the 'adjectival' (rather than the 'true possessive') sense you mention here. However, the tendency is to just drop the apostrophe rather than switch to an unusual-sounding singular modifying noun:

Childrens Home

Dogs Home

Travellers Rest

Working Mens Club

Mens Clothing Department.

( at http://dict.leo.org/forum/viewGeneraldi ... de&lang=de :

Style Manual for Authors, Editors and Printers (John Wiley & Sons):

Nonpossessive and generic phrases. In phrases such as drivers licence, travellers cheques and visitors book, the plural noun is descriptive rather than possessive. As it describes an association with the following word rather than any direct ownership, no apostrophe is necessary. Some other examples:
After primary school, she went on to the girls grammar school.
The various proofreaders marks are shown in an appendix.
Phrases such as drivers licence and travellers cheques have become merely generic ways of referring to common items. If used in a [non-, EA] generic sense, however, an apostrophe is still needed:
The young driver's licence was cancelled.)

Sorry - that link seems to have expired. However, a parallel recommendation can be found at: http://grammar.about.com/od/ab/g/apostrophepunctuationterm.htm

That's gone too. Try [this extract from The Associated Press Guide To Punctuation
By Rene J. Cappon](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=_NQ4DgAAQBAJ&pg=PT11&lpg=PT11&dq=%22Don%27t+use+apostrophes+in+such+primarily+descriptive+phrases%22&source=bl&ots=_6p_WShUuB&sig=ACfU3U36qspRz4tesoPs0i1ItrelNeEtFw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjNotWKr8HiAhXGxoUKHaAwBvQQ6AEwAXoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Don't%20use%20apostrophes%20in%20such%20primarily%20descriptive%20phrases%22&f=false) (and thanks to sumelic):

> **Descriptive Phrases Without Apostrophes**
>
> Don't use apostrophes in such primarily descriptive phrases as a New
>   York Mets outfielder, a teachers college, a writers manual, a
>   childrens book, the agencies request. As the AP Stylebook helpfully
>   notes, the apostrophe is usually skipped if 'for' or 'by' would go
>   better than 'of' in a longer version: college for teachers, manual for
>   writers, request by the agencies.
>
> In descriptive names, some organizations or institutions use the
>   apostrophe while others don't. For instance, Diners Club , and
>   National Governors Association. [both updated; EA] [The Long Island
>   Writers' Guild, Redbud Writers Guild,  The Harlem Writers Guild -
>   examples still valid, EA.] Consult your house style." (Rene J. Cappon,
>   The Associated Press Guide to Punctuation. Basic Books, 2003)

So, the awkward-looking spellings seem to be triumphing over the awkward-sounding alternatives.

Comment: If ‘drivers licence’ were really a descriptive plural rather than a mis-spelt possessive, wouldn’t it be ‘driving’ or ‘driver’ which are always correct; ‘drivers’ always questionable? 
Don’t ‘the’ and ‘on’ before ‘girls grammar…’ show the Wileys weren’t convinced?At risk of undermining my thesis, doesn’t it seem ‘dogs’ and  ‘travellers’ could be descriptive plurals; ‘childrens’ or ‘mens’ never?
Isn’t ’Don't use apostrophes in primarily descriptive phrases… ’ at least as dangerous as helpful? Won’t huge numbers of readers take that as ‘Don’t… ’ not ‘Try to find a better way of putting it.’

Comment: You are arguing from a prescriptivist ('[these] are always correct') standpoint against a descriptivist analysis. [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dogs+home%2Cdogs%27+home&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdogs%20home%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdogs%20%27%20home%3B%2Cc0) strongly suggest that <<dogs home>> is at least a plausible alternative to  <<dogs' home>>. ....

Comment: I started this answer with the hedged "There is a move away from the use of the apostrophe in the 'adjectival' " rather than "Don't use apostrophes in primarily descriptive phrases… ", and I consider your selective quoting biassed.

Comment: Thanks, Edwin. I thought I was asking for a deeper descriptivist analysis.

D’you not think that ‘childrens’ or ‘mens’ are just wrong, and however many people use them wrongly they remain wrong, in broadly the same way that speeding or parking on the pavement are wrong? Of course there’s the difference that speeding and parking on the pavement are proscribed by law and do you think the possible punishment is what matters?

Comment: On the other hand d’you think that seeking - even justifying - lowest common denominators in language is as even useful, let alone as laudable as it is in maths? Given the choice I try to go for raising standards…

Could you explain what you dislike about the quote I used?

Comment: "D’you not think that ‘childrens’ or ‘mens’ are just wrong?" Based on what criteria? Historical usage? There was no apostrophe in English prior to the 16th Century, so one could as well argue that all usages of the apostrophe are 'just wrong'. One has to accept that changes in what is acceptable English have always taken place and continue to take place, and try to keep abreast of current trends. Where there is no consensus, one mustn't argue that one preference is wrong. // "[D]oesn’t it seem ‘dogs’ and ‘travellers’ could be descriptive plurals; ‘childrens’ or ‘mens’ never?" I'd sum up ...

Comment: the situation rather by saying that plural-form attributives are fairly few in number but not unknown, and that I see no reason why 'mens' and 'childrens' should not be as acceptable as new words as say 'aggrupation', 'aiyah', 'aiyoh', and
'bracketology'. I like the differentiation afforded by say 'The dogs home is in the next street' and 'The dogs' home is in the next street', and see the extension to 'Mytholmroyd Working Mens Club' as logical for associative rather than possessive marking.

Comment: Yes,and there were hardly any books prior to the 16th Century, either. Which is more relevant, d'you think?

Other than that, I give up

Answer (score 0):

In *I write children's books* (or, less correct but equally popular, *childrens books*), *children's* is indeed a adjective. In  ?*I write children books*, *children*  would probably be taken as the object of *write*, just as in *I give children books*.  It might, as you say, be analogous to *I write horse books/ spy books*; but that has a differemt meaning; books **about** horses or spies, not for them. Education professionals might 'write children books' in this sense; but in fact the risk of confusion is so great that the phrase is not used.

Comment: @TimLymington: When does _childrens books_ become as correct as _children's books_? When it accounts for 51% of the usages? 60%? 98%? And who decides? After all, the rule must have once been 'never use an apostrophe' - before they were invented in the 16th Century.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: The obvious answer is 'when the apostrophe is abolished'.  Many people have suggested this, but I see no signs of it happening.

Comment: My question is obviously: If one or more style guides recommend usage A, and the usage is employed in half the relevant cases (as I understand you to say in this case), what justification is there for saying that not A is more correct?

Answer (score 0):

In the expression "I write children books" children is not an adjective but a noun. You might torment the verb and claim it is trivalent and that this means "I write books to children", using that American dialectic peculiarity "I wrote you letters" rather than "I wrote letters to you." You could try that sort of grammatical strappado, I doubt you'd get away with it. I think there is something about this sort of linguistic abuse in the UN charter on Human Rights.

In "I write books for children" children is also not an adjective, it is still a noun. Even if it "characterizes" the audience, it would need a noun to modify unless it is being used attributively, which it is not. "Write books for cute little children", here we have a few adjectives, but children is still a noun. Nouns self describe, though adjectives can extend the description. "We discuss this for resolution." Here the type of discussion is indeed characterized by "resolution", but it is a noun, not an adjective.

Putting it in the genitive makes it function as an adjective -- "I write children's books".
However you can also use a real adjective such as "I write juvenile books" or "I write childish books" but the latter is wrong, and the former is certainly subject to misinterpretation.

Perhaps clarity is the better part of brevity, and "I write books for children" would best convey your intent.

Comment: You should write "modify a noun" not "function as an adjective", as those are not the same thing — and here it is doing only the former.