# Formal saxon genitive usage

Tags: saxon-genitive

since James Jeans was that famous British physicist, shouldn't there be:

```
Jeans's instability
```

instead of:

```
Jeans instability
```

[(wiki link)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeans_instability#Jeans_mass)

I have read couple (maybe not all) of saxon genitive related topics here but I haven't found the answer.

Comment: "Jeans mass" is the mass of a cloud. "Jeans' mass" is the mass of Jeans himself. "Car antenna" is a type of an antenna. "Car's antenna" is the antenna belonging to a particular car. Really quite straightforward. So, do you mean to say that Jeans was instable or do you not? There's your answer right there.

Comment: @RegDwighт, and yet it is called both _Down’s syndrome_ and than _Down syndrome_. These things are not quite as regular as we’d like them to be.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, when a noun ends in *s* and it is singular, you add ***'s*** to form a Saxon genitive.This is also normally true for Christian names (for example, *St. James's park* in London).

When it comes to surnames, the matter is less clearly settled. When reading about the novels that Dickens wrote, you can find both ***Dickens's*** and ***Dickens'***. Note however that the apostrophe should always be added.

In the case you mention, I suppose that the reason for the lack of an apostrophe is that the name "Jeans" is used as an attribute of the term *instability*, meaning that it defines of which *instability* we are talking about, not something which *belongs* or *characterizes* Doctor Jeans. In other words, *Jeans* is used as an adjective and for this reason it does not change.

Comment: Yes, awareness that "Jeans" is an attribute makes it clear to me. Thank you. So, is "Jeans's instability" an incorrect form, take a look at [Jeans`length]( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeans_instability).

Comment: In the same article there is a link to [Herbig-Haro object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbig%E2%80%93Haro_object) rather than Herbig-Haro's object - same story there I would think

Comment: @Kuba, no, not incorrect at all—but not mandatory, either.

Answer (score 2):

You're begging the question by coupling the title

> Formal Saxon genitive usage

with the question

> since James Jeans was that famous British physicist, shouldn't there
>   be:
>
> Jeans's instability.

The implication is that the 'formal [S]axon gen[i]tive usage' is always mandatory.

The move towards the dropping of apostrophes in associative rather than true possessive constructions (Jeans neither designed nor bought the instability) is discussed at [Is it correct to say "I write children books" (not possessive case)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92362/is-it-correct-to-say-i-write-children-books-not-possessive-case/92364#92364) . However, here, it is not clear whether we have a dropped apostrophe (as in *Blyth Working Mens Club*) or the use of *Jeans* as a noun-modifier. The fact that your article uses *Jeans length* and *Jeans' length* right next to each other, and *Jeans instability* as well as *the Jeans instability* shows that some authorities at least can't seem to decide on a single format.

Comment: @Paola:' _Begging the question_ (Latin petitio principii, "assuming the initial point") is a type of informal fallacy in which an implicit premise would directly entail the conclusion; in other words, basing a conclusion on an assumption that is as much in need of proof or demonstration as the conclusion itself.'(Wikipedia) So would you please correct your incorrect edit. An apology would also be appreciated.

Comment: I surely apologize for wrongly assuming a spelling mistake. It's the first time I've ever heard such an expression, even in its Latin form, and I can assure you that Latin expressions are frequently used in Italian, as they are normally easy to grasp. And in the end, there's no need to sound haughty in one's remarks.

Comment: Perhaps one should check a person's site history before 'correcting' (especialy when one is at risk of making a mistake in that 'correcting'). I would have thought that the rest of the answer and linked material would suggest that a simple spelling mistake would be unlikely here. Changing a correct answer to a wrong one is simply bad practice, and contrary to the aims of this site. And perhaps a simple check - looking up "beg/ging the question" - could have avoided this misleading edit. And does a teacher sound haughty just because they are (you'd better check concord) correcting an error?

Comment: do you mean to say that I should check the usage of a plural form when the sentence starts with a singular noun? I know about it, thank you. No, what sounds haughty is your last sentence in the first comment. I surely could have read the whole answer with greater care, still making a mistake is something which may occur even to the best. For example, one may write "especially" with one "l" only, but that is clearly a typo.

Comment: Making a mistake is certainly not a cardinal sin, and I make them as well. However, I take great care to have my facts straight before I edit - not to do so would be cavalier, arrogant and potentially misleading.

Comment: @Paola: Having twice this week had a post subjected to an incorrect edit, I would reinforce Edwin's sentiment: Don't correct when you **think** something is wrong, or a typo, but only when you are **damn sure** it is wrong or a typo. When at all uncertain, post a comment to the author of the post instead.

Comment: Thank you, Pieter. (But I admit I'd like to correct the comma splice in Paola's last comment. We'll say the lower-case 'd' is a typo.)