# Why is plural -s used in "collecting stamps", but not in "stamp collecting"?

Tags: grammatical-number, linguistics

I was wondering why in some cases, both phrases mean the same thing, and one phrase has the plural *-s* and the other does not?

Eg:

> Collecting stamps (plural *-s*)
>   Stamp collecting (no plural *-s*)

Is that in the 1st scenario, the word "stamps" is a complement to the gerund "collecting" and in the 2nd scenario, "stamp" acts as an adjective and the linguistic structure of an adjective does not have the plural *-s*?

Comment: Using a plural noun as a modifier is not usually done. But it's becoming more popular.

Comment: Not quite. In "collecting stamps", "collecting" is a verb and "stamps" its direct object. In "stamp collecting", "stamp" is not an adjective, but a noun functioning as modifier of the noun "collecting".

Comment: I'm still trying to work out why there are donkey sanctuaries but dogs homes. Is it purely a function of ease of pronunciation? / 'Collecting stamp' would sound ridiculous. But the singular-form attributive is the usual choice. 'Car owners' not 'cars owners'.

Comment: Addressed at [When are attributive nouns plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7807/when-are-attributive-nouns-plural). There are other threads addressing the normal use of singular-form nouns as attributives, for instance [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/396864/singular-plural-nouns-as-adjectives/397244#397244).

Comment: After researching (looking on wikipedia that is), I found that modifier is an optional part of a phrase or clause:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_modifier
and a complement is one that is detrimental to the meaning of a phrase or clause. In both cases, isn't "stamp" or "stamps" necessary for full understanding of the phrases?

Well, and the attributive noun plurar is interesting as well, I will look further into this.

Thank you all

Comment: Note that the "science of rockets" is not (usually) "rockets science."