# Out of the words user's list or users list, which is correct

Tags: grammar

I have a list of users who are using the application then which word is correct? 
user's list or users list

Comment: Answered at [Is it correct to say 'I write children books {not possessive case}?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92362/is-it-correct-to-say-i-write-children-books-not-possessive-case/92364#92364).

Comment: It is ***users' list***.

Answer (score 18):

It's "user list" or "list of users". Consider the common phrases "grocery list" and "to-do list". The words "user", "grocery", and "to-do" in "____ list" function like adjectives, they qualify the word "list". What is it a list of? It's a list of users. What type of list is it? It's a user list.

Comment: And what about "count" and "length"? Am I naming the following variables correctly?
userCount (count of users), childCount (count of children), userArrayLength (length of the array of the users), childArrayLength (length of the array of the children).

Comment: That's correct.