# Could the attributive noun be plural?

Tags: grammar, attributive-nouns, premodifiers

> Last year, the United Nations security council adopted four **sanctions** solutions seeking to deprive North Korea of key sources...

I was taught that “attributive noun” can only be in a single form not plural.

Could you please tell me how this works?

> - when could we make (the attributive noun) plural?

[Attributive noun](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-attributive-noun-1689012)

Comment: I'd not say that either _four sanctions solutions_ or _four sanction solutions_ sounds all that natural. '... four solutions, each involving sanctions ...'. // You should have been taught that 'In English, attributive nouns are very often singular rather than plural in form'. The exceptions can be perplexing (_donkey sanctuary_ but _dogs home_), or sometimes useful (After a long and excellent dinner, he decided to visit a _singles bar_ that evening.).

Comment: I forgot to add the source. It is an article on NEW YORK TIMES. @EdwinAshworth

Comment: It doesn't matter if it was in ACGEL. If it states  'In English, attributive nouns are always singular rather than plural in form' it's incorrect.

Comment: Look into this link, it tells us that when we use the plural attributive noun, it acts like an adjective; additionally, we cannot have it with a apostrophe @EdwinAshworth  https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-attributive-noun-1689012

Comment: Have you bothered to read Cerberus's answer at the duplicate question? 'Acts like an adjective' does not mean 'becomes an adjective', and I can't find this in the Nordquist article in any case. Your linked article is also over-prescriptivist; The Long Island Writers' Guild and the The Harlem Writers Guild choose different styles. As do The Manchester Dogs Home and The Manchester and Cheshire Dogs' Home. This is discussed in a more balanced way [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92362/is-it-correct-to-say-i-write-children-books-not-possessive-case/92364#92364).

Comment: ... You seem to have glossed over ' "It is normal that the first or attributive noun of a sequence will be singular," says Geoffrey Leech. "Yet studies of recent English . . . have noted the apparently increasing variety of formations with a plural attributive noun" (Change in Contemporary English: A Grammatical Study, 2010)....


Examples include "sports car," "women leaders," and "animal rights campaign." '