# {Profession}'s Inn or {Profession}s Inn

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, apostrophe

Say you would open an inn primarily for people who build things.

Would that be called the "Builder's Inn" or the "Builders Inn"?

Comment: The trend nowadays is to use the plural attributive construction. There are probably more _working mens clubs_ than _working men's clubs_, and your example doesn't even need a novel word. There are several threads dealing with the dropping of what was once considered an obligatory apostrophe. / Though the singular form is common for attributive noun usage, it wouldn't work at all well here. Plural-form attributive nouns are not verboten (sports club / sports car / systems analyst).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it correct to say "I write children books" (not possessive case)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92362/is-it-correct-to-say-i-write-children-books-not-possessive-case). (It's perhaps worth pointing out that names can be arbitrarily chosen; one hoot named theirs "The Misplaced Apostrophe's".)

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't know the proper terminology (possessive case), so I didn't find anything online (I should add I'm non-native)
Thanks for pointing me towards that direction! And of course, names can be arbitrarily chosen - I was mostly wondering whether there was a specific general consent for Inns, given that they typically have names like this. I.e. "Adventurer's Inn"

Comment: On Google, look up <<Miners Arms>>, <<Colliers Arms>>, <<Printers Arms>> etc (using double inverted commas rather than angle brackets, and both with and without apostrophes). For Miners Arms : Miner's Arms, the ratio of hits is over 10:1.

Comment: I updated the links for duplicate questions to include several that are related, and I removed the one the pointed to a closed question.