# "Writers' Contest" or "Writers Contest"

Tags: apostrophe

Would it be correct to say "Writers' Contest" or "Writers Contest" for a competition that invites writers to submit their work? I believe there should be an apostrophe because the contest is for the noun (writers), but someone else says that the writers are not possessing the contest and instead participating in it, so there should not be an apostrophe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it correct to say "I write children books" (not possessive case)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92362/is-it-correct-to-say-i-write-children-books-not-possessive-case) Both your arguments are valid, and lead to your different versions, both acceptable. The attributive version is becoming pretty standard in cases like this. The co-existence of _X Writers Guild_ and _Y Writers' Guild_ (mentioned in the duplicate) shows that writers are undecided on this, and there's more 'ownership' involved with a guild than a contest.

Comment: Thank you for that link. I was having trouble finding anything related to my question because the word "contest" was skewing results to actual grammar contests. I'm not sure that it does answer my question because there are arguments in favour of both versions (such as the About.com/ThoughtCo article for and the AP Guide against), but perhaps that is the answer in itself: both versions can be correct depending on who you ask. I guess I was hoping for a more definitive answer.

Comment: Can you imagine a letter '... to _my good friends at X Writers Guild and Y Writers' Guild_ ...  I consider you to be the two best ... er ... guilds for writers in the country'?