# Number of genitive object in a nominal compound

Tags: phrases, grammatical-number, writing-style, attributive-nouns, of-genitive

Which of the following options is better? Do the two choices reflect any difference in meaning?

"Matters regarding comments deletion"

*or*

"Matters regarding comment deletion"

--Assuming the intended meaning is "Matters regarding [deletion of comments]"?

---

Running list of related and duplicate questions:

[Pluralization rules with prepositional phrases](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/425983/pluralization-rules-with-prepositional-phrases)

[Plural nouns in nominal compounds](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48636/plural-nouns-in-nominal-compounds)

[When are attributive nouns plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7807/when-are-attributive-nouns-plural)

https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/85654/how-can-i-explain-to-a-non-native-why-the-plural-of-a-noun-isnt-used-adjectival

Answer (score 0):

> --Assuming the intended meaning is "Deletion of comments"?

*comments* - Since it is in plural form, **Comments Deletion** is correct usage.

---

**Edit**:

> "Matters regarding comments deletion"

(Various) Matters regarding deletion of (multiple) comments

> "Matters regarding comment deletion"

(Various) Matters regarding deletion of (a) comment

Hence, the first sentence will convey the intended meaning

Comment: But what would be the difference in meaning? (Please see my edits to the question.)

Comment: @SAH - See my updated answer, please.

Comment: But the tricky part is that "Deletion of Comments" implies a global matter, not just an individual comment(s)' being deleted. KWIM?

Comment: Can you provide context and a proper sentence? i am unable to understand. From your example, only the position of the subject and verb changes. Going by the intended meaning, it should take the plural form

Comment: When used as adjectives, many nouns appear in the singular even though their meaning is semantically plural. For example, a *grocery list* and not a *groceries list* (you're usually buying *groceries* and not a single *grocery*), a *book store* (they undoubtedly have more than one book in stock), and a *horse race* (you can't have a race if there's only one horse). I would argue that *comment deletion* is ***not*** incorrect, and in fact is the more usual form in English.