# Which of "game names" and "games names" is correct?

Tags: grammatical-number, attributive-nouns

What it's supposed to designate:

*A list of the name of each game.*

So there are multiple games and therefore multiple names.

But should either or both take an `s` at the end in `a list of game(s) name(s)` ?

Comment: As with, say, ***car radios***, the first word in ***game names*** is a "noun adjunct" usage (noun used as adjective). They're invariably *singular*.

Comment: Alright, thanks ! If you wish to post an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: [In English, the norm is that nouns incorporated into compounds **do not take a plural** ending.](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/48680/2637)

Comment: @FF Very often singular.

Comment: @Edwin: Wot? So I should have highlighted **the norm is that** as well as **do not take a plural**? Or is it just that my **invariably** means ***almost** always*, not necessarily *every single time, **without exception**?*

Comment: @FF '... a "noun adjunct" usage (noun used as adjective). They're invariably singular.'

Comment: Uh… sorry to say it but no, it can't be that your "invariably" means almost always, not necessarily every single time, without exception or anything similar.

"Invariably" means always, necessarily every single time, without exception. If you meant something else, please use some word other than means almost always, not necessarily every single time, without exception or anything similar.

If you meant something else, please use a word quite differ from "Invariably".

Comment: Sorry I was so harsh before… even though it was true.

When such lists are invariably singular, what does that say about the very popular idea of lists - even books! - full of boys' names or girls' names, please?

It might be argued that those should be boy's names or girl's names and then, how would we accommodate children's names?

Are you really saying those should be boy names, girl names or child names?

Answer (score 0):

The games' names are Scrabble, Monopoly, etc.

Game names can be anything from silly to serious.

Really depends on context.