# Computer graphic designer vs. Computer graphics designer

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Some English-speaking people call them "computer *graphic* designers" while others call them "computer *graphics* designers."

I doubt they have different meanings, but I wonder why they have to use it differently when they are the same. Please advise me if they are different.

I would find anyone strange if he or she calls himself or herself a *webs* designer instead of a *web* designer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When are attributive nouns plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7807/when-are-attributive-nouns-plural)

Answer (score 1):

The more correct term is "Computer graphics designer" as the word "computer" here is describing the type of graphics.  It could be reworded "designer of computer graphics."

Rather in the title "Computer graphic designer," graphic is an adjective therefore computer cannot be referring to "graphic".  In a sense, it is as if you are saying a designer that is both graphic and involves computers.

As above, web designer can be reworded as "designer of the web".  I suppose web designer is different in this respect because while a computer graphics designer designs "computer graphics", a web designer designs "the web" since web here is always used singularly.

I hope that answers your question!

Comment: I think you're on point with this analysis. Web designer is actually a short form of website designer, so that's also correct.

Comment: @JohnHamilton Good point, though websites designer wouldn't be entirely wrong even if you never hear it used.

Comment: Because 'graphic' is far from unknown as a noun,  'in ... "Computer graphic designer," graphic is an adjective' needs supporting evidence. The behaviour of attributive nouns is not simple (dogs home vs donkey sanctuary), and usually the singular form is the default choice. Idiomaticity (what people usually use) is the only way to approach this, and arguments from logic are usually unhelpful. But the general issue of singular vs plural attributive nouns has been covered on ELU before.