# What is the proper way to use the word buyer/buyers to describe our real estate company?

Tags: grammatical-number

What would be considered the proper way to call our company -

A. Exclusive Buyer Agency, LLC 
B. Exclusive Buyers Agency, LLC

I have registered the company name as Exclusive Buyer Agency but wanted to know if I should change it.
Thank you for your time in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When are attributive nouns plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7807/when-are-attributive-nouns-plural)

Comment: The degree of complexity is increased with the vague meaning of "Exclusive" being either "one and only" or "swanky" as in "fashionable."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because naming things is off topic.

Answer (score 2):

This is a potato—potato question. Either form is proper usage.
In A, the implication is that the agency itself is the sole referent.
In B, the implication is that the agency represents/is composed of different individual buyers.

Comment: So in the case of A, is it describing itself as the sole agency working for a buyer? And in the case of B, is it describing the agency as an agency that works with many buyers exclusively?