# Should "words" be plural in "The Words Hunters"?

Tags: grammatical-number, attributive-nouns

I'm creating an educational game that teaches English words and I wanted to call it: "The Word Hunter". But there's a famous book named *Word Hunters* and I don't want to have any copyright problem so I decided to go with "The Words Hunters" (yeah, my brain hurts XD).

Is the use of the plural "words" correct in this title?

Comment: I agree with the answer. But I can think of several variations: *The Hunters of Words*, *Hunting Words*, *The Word Seekers*, *The Word Sleuths*, *The Word Stalkers*. I could go on . . . ;)

Comment: Thank you! Great options indeed.  Hunting Words and The Word Sleuths sound perfect! You will receive proper credit for it XD. Greetings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When are attributive nouns plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7807/when-are-attributive-nouns-plural)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, no.

The word *words* is an attributive noun, which functions as an adjective. Adjectives in English are not inflected for number, so even if you are hunting more than one word, *Words* in your title should be singular.

There are many examples: *window cleaner* and *dog catcher* come to mind immediately; and even things like *trouser press* and *scissor jump* where the attributive noun is usually plural only use them in the singular.

That said, it's your title.