# If you have a collection of something, is the something writen in plural?

Tags: grammatical-number, collective-nouns

A collection like in:

- A list of users
- A group of cities

When attaching this as we do in software development to name variables, should it be named

- userList vs usersList
- cityGroup vs citiesGroup

which one is syntactically more correct?

Comment: I'm not sure that variable naming is required (or should be required) to follow English language rules, e.g. camel casing _isn't_ syntactically correct in English.

Comment: well, that was only to set the context of the question

Comment: The first question needs basic research, and if this was found to provide an inadequate answer would be suitable for ELL. The second question is a duplicate of [When are attributive nouns plural {in form?}](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7807/when-are-attributive-nouns-plural).

Comment: This is an issue of convention for development, not proper English. If you look at Airbnb's style guide (e.g., https://guide.meteor.com/code-style.html), you'd normally call a list a plural thing all by itself. So a "list of users" would be "Users" not "userList" or "userList". In javascript, you can say idiomatic things then like Users.forEach(user=>user.blunk). This is more of a question to ask on programming.SE, where the answers will be relevant.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be migrated to programming.SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that the plural is used in phrases such as "a list of users". However, your variable-names copy a different sort of phrase in English. This is where a noun (the head noun) is modified by a noun coming before the head noun. In this case the modifier is generally in the singular(1). Thus we would write "user list", and thus the variable-name would be better as userList.

(1) There are exceptions, such as "jeans pocket", but in those cases the modifier is a noun which is not normally used in the singular. Your examples are not of this exceptional type.

Comment: Yes. A "collector of stamps" is a "stamp collector". And his/her pride and joy is their "stamp collection". And the missing object might be either in my "jeans pocket" or my "coat pocket".