# Automotive: "Part-makers" or "Parts Makers"?

Tags: terminology, grammatical-number, word-usage, phrase-usage

I see the term "parts maker" in use a lot in automotive industry news, and I'm wondering if the term is a correct construction (grammatically speaking).

When this term is used in Japanese it is always written with an S sound on the end (whether talking about one or more than one): パーツメーカー So this may contribute to the frequent inclusion of the S in English as well - at least in documents translated from Japanese. However, such cases most likely represent a relatively small percentage.

Web searches produce inconsistent results. Note this Wikipedia page, for example:

[**Category:Auto parts suppliers**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Auto_parts_suppliers)

There are subcategories here such as "Motorcycle part**s** manufacturers" and "Automotive part retailers‎". So depending on the word that follows "part", the S may be included or excluded.

Let's compare the usage using Google Trends:

### Maker:

[image: Maker]

### Supplier:

[image: Supplier]

### Manufacturer:

[image: Manufacturer]

Why is there so much inconsistency here? And what do English scholars have to say about this?

Comment: It seems logical to me to use _parts_, as it refers to many different components of a car.

Comment: @KateBunting I know what you mean. But is there any sort of rule that governs this? If a metal refinery processes many different kinds of metals is it logical to call it a *metals refinery*? That sounds unnatural to me - but according to Google that usage is not uncommon if we are discussing "precious metals". It all seems like a big grey area the more I examine it.

Comment: "Donkey sanctuary" and "dogs home" are standard (well, a few traditionalists might still cling on to "dogs' home"). You just have to go with what's idiomatic (what most well-informed native speakers actually use), often by-passing what might be more logical and being especially wary of looking for inviolable patterns.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When are attributive nouns plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7807/when-are-attributive-nouns-plural) Note that (1) attributive nouns default to (/usually are) in singular form, but (2) there are exceptions, especially when emphasising a plurality seems sensible. And here, I'd say _parts maker_ trips slightly more easily off the tongue – usually the deciding factor.

Comment: The hyphenation makes it strange. Somebody or something that is *part-maker* suggests that they only *partially* do that. For instance, they could also be *part-baker* or *part-farmer*. Whether the noun should be *part maker* or *parts maker* (and the plural is more common for *this* phrase), a hyphen would normally not be used.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, that demystifies it for me. Thank you. Since there are so many exceptions to the default singular form, it must be difficult for those learning English as a second language. And there are many cases (such as "part(s) manufacturer") in which there is no consensus, even among native speakers. But I will accept this as just one of the quirky aspects of English, and move on with life. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯