# Computers as a class

Tags: american-english, computing

I was just going through some book and found a word "computers" used as a class (like computer class).
But in my generation, we called it a computer class, never "computers."
Can anyone tell me what English speaking countries use this expression?

Comment: I don’t understand the question. Can you clarify the context?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange!  Please say what book this is. What is the title and author. Does it say what country it was written for? We also need the sentence in which this word occurred. It is impossible to answer just from knowing one word.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When are attributive nouns plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7807/when-are-attributive-nouns-plural) Singular-form rather than plural-form attributive nouns are nearly always (but not always) chosen. Although in this particular case, _computing class_ would surely be the idiomatic term.

Comment: It is unclear whether 'computer(s) class' here means something like a type of computers or a course of education about computers. Either way the question linked by Mr. Ashworth seems to provide an adequate answer. The phrase (with either the plural or the singular) is not often used in the latter sense: a course of such education would usually be referred to by its more specific topic: the use of particular software, particular aspect of programming, repairing a particular type of hardware, erc.

Comment: hum...Yeah I get your point. My question was pretty ambiguous. I mean do you guys use "computers" for "computer class." The sentence was "I have computers on Monday" and it said it was used in American context.

Comment: I'm not American but I'd imagine that even if (when given its full name) the class is called "computer class", you might still abbreviate it to  "computers" if you're missing out the word "class" and simply saying "I have computers on Monday".  To me, that makes sense.