# Artifact or artifacts reduction

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, attributive-nouns

I need to explain to someone why it's grammatically incorrect to use "artifacts reduction" as opposed to "artifact reduction." Can anyone help with an explanation?

Comment: A little more context might help. I think you are asking about why "reduction of artifacts" changes to "artifact reduction" -- when you invert the wording, you change from a plural noun to a singular form as an adjective. An experienced linguist should be able to define the terms better than I -- if that is indeed your question.

Comment: If there are multiple artifacts involved(whether they're of similar type or not), then 'artifacts reduction' is also correct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When are attributive nouns plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7807/when-are-attributive-nouns-plural) The default situation is the use of the single-form noun (Boy Scouts not Boys Scouts, car lanes not cars lanes, donkey sanctuaries ...', though quite a few exceptions exist (systems analyst/s, dogs home/s, writers guild/s ...). Each pairing has to be examined to determine standard usage. Sometimes, there is an option.

Comment: But it's ***not*** "grammatically incorrect" to refer to ***artifacts reduction**!* It's just idiomatically less common.

Comment: Alternatively, one might say that it *is* grammatically incorrect, because an attributive noun is functioning as an adjective, and adjectives in English are not inflected for number. [There are always exceptions, as Cerberus's linked answer demonstrates, but that doesn't make the generality wrong.]