# Values manager vs. value manager

Tags: technical

When writing software documentation I very often have to describe things like a *value manager*, a *value cache* or a *device map*. These are usually components of the software system.

In practice the *manager* does of course not manage a single *value* but many and the *map* does not map only a single *device* etc.

My question is: is it more common to speak of a *values manager* instead of a *value manager* and of a *devices map* instead of a *device map* etc.?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When are attributive nouns plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7807/when-are-attributive-nouns-plural)

Comment: No, it is common to use nouns as adjectives without the s.

Comment: @StuartF thanks, yes, I think it answers most of it. I'm not sure, whether my focus on technical documentation makes any difference though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The job title is awkward but clear enough. “Value” is about cost estimates, savings, and such. “Values” is about watching the moral compass.

Comment: Sorry the example wasn't the best for the title. "Device manager" vs. "Devices manager" would have been better. You would still go for singular in the other examples?

Comment: @NicolasR. Generally yes, unless the manager runs a department or project whose name is in plural. Device manager (or map), absolutely. But: Parts manager, sales manager, public relations manager, because those departments are Parts, Sales, etc.