# Noun phrase: test status and tests status valid?

Tags: phrases, nouns

I am wondering if I can use “test status” phrase for a status of one test, and if I can use “tests status” as status of three tests? Also what is the linguistic rule behind it and/or have you seen this before? Need to modify a table on a software page.

Comment: What is a test "status" in this context?

Comment: Each test result under the column head has one status. So *Test Status* for the column head.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When are attributive nouns plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7807/when-are-attributive-nouns-plural) The default is singular-form attributive nouns (one bottle top, sixteen bottle tops) though there are exceptions, as Cerberus says. Here, 'tests status' sounds poor; if you must, 'the status of the various tests' indicates plurality, though 'test status' covers this also.