# What is the rule for word formation in "object"+"person"(like babysitter, songwriter, etc)?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

Could you please explain what rule do you use when you make "double" words like babysitter, headhunter, songwriter,  calorie burner?

Why is the first word singular? Not *babies*sitter (If it means a person who sits with not only one, but with many babies)? Not *songs*writer? Something like body builder is singular because you have one body, but why are the others not plural?

You can change position and say "writer of songs", and now it is plural. It is because it would be harder to pronounce?

Comment: If this is just about the plurality of such nouns, it's answered by [When are attributive nouns plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/7807/191178)

Comment: Generally speaking, nouns modifying other nouns can't be plural. That's why *_shoes store_ is wrong, even though one always buys shoes in pairs.

Comment: I'm not sure that 'fieldsman',  'swordsman',  'batsman' even should be considered as [Npl + N] compound nouns. Though 'sportsman' looks a likelier candidate.

Comment: Note also that the rule about 'making up new words' is basically 'you can't'. Although nobody will object if you slip in the odd D-I-Y-ism in informal contexts (provided it can be clearly understood), a word needs currency too. Perhaps you are asking about the rules governing the morphology of existing [N + N] compound nouns?

Comment: The OED says fieldsman, swordsman, sportsman, etc, are derived from possessives, although as other questions say there are some compounds with a plural like singles bar and lice comb, and some which vary like pension(s) adviser. Whatever is easier and less ambiguous.

Comment: This is a hardy perennial from non-native speakers, who may be unaware of SE English Language Learners. The short answer is because the language is English, not French etc.

Comment: "Stuart F:Etymon agrees for 'swordsman' but avers that 'sportsman' comes from the plural form _sports_.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the first noun is in the function of an adjective. When a noun takes on the role of an adjective, it usually does so in its singular form.

Comment: "Function as" wrongly conflates mere **parts of speech** with actual **syntactic functions**  (also called grammatical roles). But those two are **not** the same thing. These do not *“function”* as adjectives: they function as ***modifiers.***  "Adjective" not a syntactic function; "modifier" is. If they "functioned" as adjectives, they'd enjoy such adjectival properties as being modifiable by adverbs. But they cannot be; instead they are modifiable by adjectives. Why? **Because they are nouns.** Period.