# Is it correct to say "violation list" or is it correct to say "violations list"

Tags: attributive-nouns

[This](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7807/when-are-attributive-nouns-plural) question has general rules, but it leaves open the exception(s) list.

So my question here is specifically about "violation(s) list".

Comment: Explain yourself. What does it mean, and why should it be an exception?

Comment: Examples of **violations list** can be found in [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22violations+list%22) and the [NGram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=violation+list%2Cviolations+list&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: @StuartF If you see the answer to the linked question, bullet 3 says there is a list of exception where plural is used. I was asking if my particular case is an exception.

Comment: @DjinTonic cool idea and answers my question, thanks. I will use this tricks to find examples in the future.

Comment: For more on plural attributive nouns see the chapter "Of Mice and Men" in Steven Pinker's *Words and Rules*.

Answer (score 0):

In general if you have an "X of Ys", you will call it a "Y X" -- without the plural s.

Examples: a zoo of only giraffes would be a "giraffe zoo", not a "giraffes zoo"; and a game based on coins would be a "coin game", not a "coins game".
There are a few idiomatic exceptions (e.g. "games room") but they *are* exceptions.

A list of violations would be a "violation list" and not a "violations list".

One example (1978: US Congress, "Arson-for-hire"): "The FBI won't put anything on the uniform crime list or they request the chiefs of police not to put anything on **the crime list** unless it falls under one of those three missions that you just mentioned." -- That's a list of multiple crimes, but it's a "crime list".

Comment: [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=violation+list%2Cviolations+list&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) would seem to indicate that in this particular case, the situation is fluid, with the plural-form attributive noun more in evidence in some years. However, the singular form seems preferred at the moment (as is usually the case). 'Crime/s list' behave quite similarly, but these things don't pattern reliably.