# Is it correct to say "lesson count" or "lessons count"?

Tags: grammatical-number, attributive-nouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“user accounts” or “users account”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/user-accounts-or-users-account)

If I mean "number of lessons", which grammatical construction should I go for? I can imagine three of them:

1. Lesson count
2. Lessons count
3. Lessons' count