# "BookList" or "booksList?"

Tags: grammatical-number, attributive-nouns

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [“User accounts” or “users account?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/user-accounts-or-users-account)
>   [Is it correct to say “lesson count” or “lessons count”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14115/is-it-correct-to-say-lesson-count-or-lessons-count)

I'm wondering whether or not I should use a plural form noun with a collection name. For example, which one is correct, *bookList* or *booksList* (obviously they are variables in a programming language)?

Comment: `variable_names` (I don't like CamelCase much :-) are better off following rules of logic rather than rules of English.  If this isn't a dup, it must be off-topic.

Comment: @Rhodri: CamelCase is generally a preference of the language being used. I would advice against fighting the norm if anyone else needs to read your code; your discomfort is less than the discomfort of everyone following behind you.

Answer (score 16):

I'd prefer *bookList*. After all, nobody uses a books shelf, either, but a book shelf.

Answer (score 9):

Why aren't you using `books` instead of `bookList`? If this is in an object oriented language, the variable will be declared as `List *books` which clarifies that `books` is a `List`.

Putting the variable type in the variable is fine but it isn't needed as much as it was in the past. If you really want "list" in the var name somewhere I would recommend `bookList` if it is a list of `Book` objects (or whatever you are using for a book.)

I would never use `booksList`. If you are storing lists of lists of books I would recommend finding a term other than "book." Library, shelf or `bookLists` may work. Essentially, a plural at the end of a variable flags it as a container for objects of whatever was just pluralized. `books` is a container of `book`. `cats` is a bag of `cat`. `dogLists` is a container of `dogList`.

Answer (score 3):

- Use *bookList* to store a list of individual books.
- Use *booksList* (or *bookListList*) to store a list of lists of books.

Comment: For the second example I would prefer bookLists instead of booksList.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I think of is [Booklist magazine](http://www.ala.org/ala/aboutala/offices/publishing/booklist_publications/booklist/booklist.cfm), a reasonably well-known publication of the American Library Association.

I'd go with bookList regardless, because it's easier to say (or subvocalize).
But I think both are reasonable forms, so if you like one or the other, go with that one.

Answer (score 0):

`List` implies a collection of objects, the object type in the variable name implies that each element in the collection is a single `Book` as opposed to each element being another collection of `Books`,  in the plural.
If the second case were true, and we were dealing with a multi dimensional array of objects, it would make more sense to use different collective noun to describe the outer collection rather than `Books`.

e.g.

- libraryList is a list of libraries, each library contains a bookshelfList

  - bookshelfList is a list of bookshelves, each bookshelf contains a bookList

    - bookList is a list of books