# Thing count or thingS count

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, attributive-nouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“User accounts” or “users account”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/user-accounts-or-users-account)
>   [Should a list of tokens be called a “token list” or a “tokens list”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59059/should-a-list-of-tokens-be-called-a-token-list-or-a-tokens-list)
>   [“BookList” or “booksList?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17329/booklist-or-bookslist)

When there are many of things what of the following will be correct:

- thing count, thing collection, ... (singular `thing`)
- thing**s** count, thing**s** collection, ... (plural `things`) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use the singular form before *collection* because you are describing the singular type of the collection, like an adjective. After, you would use plural, because you are describing what comprises the collection. For example:

> A doll collection
>
> A stamp collection

versus

> A collection of dolls
>
> A collection of stamps