# "feed aggregator" instead of "feeds aggregator"

Tags: grammatical-number, attributive-nouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it correct to say “lesson count” or “lessons count”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14115/is-it-correct-to-say-lesson-count-or-lessons-count)

I find it odd that the common expression (see Wikipedia for example) is "feed aggregator" rather than "feed*s* aggregator". I would find the plural more meaningful with the concept of aggregating :). Does this happen in other English expressions? Why?