# "Book market" or "books market"

Tags: grammatical-number

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“User accounts” or “users account”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/user-accounts-or-users-account)

Which is correct: *book market* or *books market*? Similarly, is it *pirate bay* or *pirates bay*?

Comment: Could you provide more context?

Comment: Related: [“User accounts” or “users account”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/user-accounts-or-users-account) ¦ [“feed aggregator” instead of “feeds aggregator”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61891/feed-aggregator-instead-of-feeds-aggregator)

Answer (score 1):

'Book Market' is the correct definition for a market where books are sold. It could be one certain book's market, however a market is not commonly in possession of one book, so no.

Same with 'Pirate Bay' (that is the correct definition), it could be a bay that is in possession of pirates, and in that case it would be "Pirates' Bay" with an apostrophe at the end of pirates (plural possession), but as a name it would always be 'Pirate Bay'.