# Task breakdown vs Tasks breakdown vs Tasks' breakdown

Tags: word-choice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“User accounts” or “users account”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/user-accounts-or-users-account)
>   [should a list of tokens be called a “token list” or a “tokens list”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59059/should-a-list-of-tokens-be-called-a-token-list-or-a-tokens-list)
>   [“Book market” or “books market”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72934/book-market-or-books-market)

Which one(s) are correct to indicate the division in(to) tasks of a certain undertaking?

```
1) Task breakdown
2) Tasks breakdown
3) Tasks' breakdown
```

I would like to understand the "why" of it rather than get an Ngram-like usage statistics chart, please.