# "Contact group" or "Contacts group"?

Tags: grammatical-number

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“User accounts” or “users account?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/user-accounts-or-users-account)

I'm writing software, and I need to create an object that will contain a group of contacts. Contacts can belong to more than one group.

If I wanted to shorten "group of contacts," would I refer to it as a contacts group, or a contact group?

Comment: Per the [FAQ](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq): "But please, don’t ask any questions about these topics. They are out of scope for this site. . . . * How to name this function/variable in my program."

Comment: @zpletan Alright, I get it. But forgetting about the program, I still have the grammar doubt: should the noun to be grouped be plural or singular?

Comment: See the linked question. Also related: [“BookList” or “booksList”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17329/booklist-or-bookslist), [“lesson count” or “lessons count”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14115/is-it-correct-to-say-lesson-count-or-lessons-count), and lots of others. The answer is always the same.