# Multiple plural, any rules?

Tags: grammatical-number

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“User accounts” or “users account?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/user-accounts-or-users-account)

What is correct way to use *-s* when talking about multiple plurals?

For example, what is correct: *items positions* or *item positions* or *items position*? In context: "I will update all items positions".

What is correct *cars categories* or *car categories* or *cars category*? In context: "Please tell me what cars categories do you know?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first example, you can use all the constructs you suggest. In **items' positions** (you need the apostrophe to make this better) **all** modifies both nouns. In **item** ***positions***, **all** modifies only **positions** but the meaning stays the same: the items in question have different positions. In **items' position**, **all** modifies **items**, meaning that all the items have the same position.

In your second example, the one that sounds natural English is **car categories**. **Cars'** ***categories*** doesn't sound ungrammatical, but I'd use the first one. As for **cars category**, it means that there are many cars but only one category, which doesn't look very likely.

Comment: so u are saying what?
Users Accounts? or User Accounts?

Answer (score 1):

In your examples, the first nouns *item* and *car* are modifying the second nouns *position* and *category*. Typically in this kind of construction, the first noun is singular (e.g., *a tooth brush*, not **a teeth brush*) regardless of the number of things you're talking about. The second noun, which is the head of your noun phrase, can be singular or plural.